# Access violation writing location 0x00000000. C++ / SFML game

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a school project using C++ and SFML 2.0, it's due for Tuesday and I've just recently run in to this problem. 
I've put an arrow on where the latest Call Stack is.
These are the code parts that I suspect might have something wrong in them. I'm also very new to c++ and I know I do alot of things wrong.

This is in my `Background` class, it loads all my tiles, sets their position and tiletype and so on.

The `GetWayPointList` returns a vector of tiles to my `EnemyManager` class

```
void Background::Load(QuadTree * quadTree) {

        int tempTiles[32][32] = {... Lots of 1's and 0's in here };

        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
--->                    tile[j][i]->tileType = tempTiles[j][i];
                    tile[j][i]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f((float)(i*32),(float)(j*32)));
                    if(tile[j][i]->tileType == 1)
                    {
                        quadTree->AddObject(tile[j][i]);            
                    }

                else if(tile[j][i]->tileType == 0)
                {
                    tile[j][i]->distanceFromStart = INT_MAX;
                    tile[j][i]->parent = NULL;

                    vector<Tile*> tempTiles;
                    if(tile[j+1][i]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j+1][i]);
                    if(tile[j-1][i]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j-1][i]);
                    if(tile[j][i+1]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j][i+1]);
                    if(tile[j][i-1]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j][i-1]);
                    tile[j][i]->setSuccessors(tempTiles);
                    tilesList->push_back(tile[j][i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

vector<Tile*>* Background::GetWayPointList()
{
    return tilesList;
}
```

The Call Stack itself says `TileShooter v0.1.exe!Background::Load(QuadTree*quadTree) Line 68 + 0x2e bytes`. 
Line 68 is where the arrow is.

If you need more code / info just say.
Any points on what's possibly wrong would be greatly appriciated.
Best Regards, Fredrik W

---

**Edit**

I've edited the code some including `tile[j][i] = new Tile();`

```
void Background::Load(QuadTree * quadTree) {

        int tempTiles[32][32] = {... Lots of 1's and 0's in here };

        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                    tile[j][i] = new Tile();
                    tile[j][i]->tileType = tempTiles[j][i];
                    tile[j][i]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f((float)(i*32),(float)(j*32)));
                    if(tile[j][i]->tileType == 1)
                    {
                        quadTree->AddObject(tile[j][i]);            
                    }

                else if(tile[j][i]->tileType == 0)
                {
                    tile[j][i]->distanceFromStart = INT_MAX;
                    tile[j][i]->parent = NULL;

                    vector<Tile*> tempTiles;
---->                   if(tile[j+1][i]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j+1][i]);
                    if(tile[j-1][i]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j-1][i]);
                    if(tile[j][i+1]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j][i+1]);
                    if(tile[j][i-1]->tileType == 0)
                        tempTiles.push_back(tile[j][i-1]);
                    tile[j][i]->setSuccessors(tempTiles);
                    tilesList->push_back(tile[j][i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

vector<Tile*>* Background::GetWayPointList()
{
    return tilesList;
}
```

That didn't really solve but rather moved the error downwards, I've moved my arrow on where the Call Stack has it's latest call.

Comment: Where do you define `tile`? I guess your problem is that `tile` is either too small or not yet allocated or the elements in `tile` are not allocated.

Comment: Tile is defined in the Background.h as Tile* tile[32][32];

Comment: Never understood the obsession in schools over gigantic, multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Through your edit, you've made my answer make no sense.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - We should probably call them "old schools" but nevertheless you are right.

Answer (score 4):

So your `tile` member is defined as `Tile* tile[32][32]`. That's a 2D array of size 32x32 where each element is a pointer to `Tile`. However, they are *just* pointers and currently don't point anywhere in particular - accessing them is undefined behaviour (in your case, an access violation). You need to allocate the actual `Tile` objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
    tile[i][j] = new Tile();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to do the same kind of loop in the destructor of `Background` that instead does `delete tile[i][j];`.

Better yet, don't dynamically allocate your tiles and just define `tile` as:

```
Tile tile[32][32];
```

Even better yet (!), use `std::array<std::array<Tile,32>,32>`. :)

---

To answer your edit, even though it's invalidated my above answer: You're accessing the `j+1`th element of `tile`. When `j` is 31, you're accessing `tile[32]` which is outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - I wonder what could be achieved if we could use a force of all bored C++ programmers in the world.

Comment: @SChepurin: Did you see the episode of Doctor Who where Martha Jones defeats the Master? And how she did it? _That's_ what could be achieved.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - Living in "alternate reality" most of my life i have no idea who is Dr. Who )